# Javascript building element reference node list

Tags: javascript

How can i build a nodelist, which is reference to the selected node?
Example **document.querySelectorAll('tr')** returns a nodelist contains all the tr element node references on page.
I`m writing methods, to return element nodelist references by search criteria.

But if i using **insertBefore, appendChild**, etc... this function will remove the nodes from the elements.
Example i have a 4x4 table, and i want to return the first 2 rows:

```
var nl = document.createDocumentFragment();
el = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
for ( var a = 0; a < 2 && a < el.length; a++)
{
    nl.appendChild(el[a]);
}
console.log(nl);
```

This nl returns the first 2 rows of the table, but it will removes from the document. Removed from the DOM and append to nl as child.

I want to retrieve only the node(s) reference like querySelectorAll as a list, not as documentFragment childNodes.

Any idea how to archieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to move things around in the DOM, don't use the methods that move things around!

```
var nl = new Array();
var el = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
for ( var a = 0; a < 2 && a < el.length; a++)
{
    nl.push(el[a]);
}
```

Comment: Wow, works like a charm. Just I`m a bit cofused, document nodeList is not an array, its a collection, just array-like.

Comment: I'm not certain what you are asking there.  javascript doesn't have anything called a collection.

Comment: Just a little documentation:
What is a NodeList?

NodeLists are very similar to Array collections of elements, often referred to as “array-like”, but with a subtle difference - you’re missing out on a lot of JavaScript functionality by keeping your collection as a NodeList, such as true Array iteration and Prototypal methods.

Source: [DOM Doc](https://toddmotto.com/a-comprehensive-dive-into-nodelists-arrays-converting-nodelists-and-understanding-the-dom/)

Comment: Right.  A node list is an `object` that quacks like an array.  There's no type called `collection` in js.  Anyhow, was there a question there or just the statement?